# Pinch-zoom image and scrollview - not behaves good together

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-scrollview, pinchzoom

I developed an imagegallery where its possible to pinch and zoom. With just a click on an actual image its loaded to a fragment where one can pinch and zoom.
This works fine! the sourcecode for zooming is a library a found and is implemented in the code via xml.

A problem arised when I came with the idea to have a text beneath the zoomable image and when the text becomes long I have to wrap the linearlayout with its childs in a scrollview. What happends that the pinch and zoom now does not work properly - I can zoom and pinch as before but its kind of slow and is not smooth any more.

Any ideas what the cause to this is and if there is any easy solutions? May it be hard to combine a scrollview and pinch and zoom imageview?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="0sp" 
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <se.sources.thai.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/text_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="img1"/>

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text_img_text"
     style="@style/MyTextViewTheme" 
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />


   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this library for pinch zooming ability: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

As said in "Features", it works perfectly in a scrolling parent.